# How to get Input value of client side using server side control in asp.net, c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Hello guys i am new in asp.net .i want to get values of inputbox using server contol (asp.net ,c#) but am not getting null values of inputbox .any one help me?
Thanks in advance.

my code sample is as follows

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">
       Current Location<span class="text-red">*</span>
    </label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" class="form-control" ID="txtCurrentLocation" name="txtCurrentLocation" type="text">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCurrentLocation" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCurrentLocation" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required!" CssClass="sfRequired" ValidationGroup="UpdateCourier">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>

<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="btnUpdateCourier_Click" class="btn btn-blue" ID="btnUpdateCourier" ToolTip="Update" Text="Update" ValidationGroup="UpdateCourier" />
```

//my server-side code

```
protected void btnUpdateCourier_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string courier=  txtCurrentLocation.Text;
}
```

why "txtCurrentLocation.Text" gives null value?

Comment: Are you updating value of textbox on pageload?

Comment: @Hemal i want to Get' txtCurrentLocation' value on "btnUpdateCourier" click, is it possible ?